# ArrayList<Object> how to differentiate objects added

Tags: java, arraylist

the question is the same as in the title. i have arraylist to which i add incomes or expenses both in form of a object. will this loop sum up all elements, and is there a better way of doing this :?

```
    public void sumOfAllExpAndIn(){
    int tmp = 0;
    for (Iterator<Object> it = database.iterator(); it.hasNext();){

        if (it.next() instanceof Expenses){
            Expenses excalc = new Expenses();
            excalc = (Expenses) it.next();
            tmp -= excalc.value;
        }
        else {
            incomes incalc =new incomes();
            incalc = (incomes) it.next();
            tmp += incalc.value;
        }
    }
    System.out.format("the overall balance is %d",tmp);
}
```

Comment: No. Every time you call .next you will move to the next value, so the code you posted will skip at least half the `incomes` objects, and throw an exception if there is an odd-numbered run of `incomes` objects. You need to read it out once *then* check the type. But also you should consider using an abstract base class (or interface) which has an overridable method to perform the action, then you don't need to check its type at all.

Comment: Generics was created to answer your question. Why would you even add two different types of objects into a single Collection anyways. You need to follow the Generics tutorial provided by Oracle to understand how to answer your question. Your code is not wrong, but it is ugly, and bulky and potentially not type-safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there are several better ways of doing it.

Firstly, I don't suggest you declare it as an Object list. Better is to declare an interface and then implement the interface in each of your classes:

```
interface BudgetValue {
    double getValue();
}

class Expense implements BudgetValue {
    public double getValue() {
        return -value;
    }
}

class Income implements BudgetValue {
    public double getValue() {
        return +value;
    }
}
```

Then you can declare list of BudgetValues rather than Objects as the input to your method:

```
double sumBudgetValues(List<BudgetValues> budgetValues) {
}
```

There are two easy ways of summing them:

```
double total = 0.0;
for (BudgetValue value: budgetValues) {
    total += value.getValue();
}
return total;
```

or using Java 8:

```
return budgetValues.stream()
    .mapToDouble(BudgetValue::getValue)
    .sum().orElse(0.0);
```

The streams method makes a lot more sense to me and allows it to be easily multithreaded if you have a lot of values to sum by turning it into a parallel stream.

There are some rare occassions where `instanceof` is justified but, as a rule of thumb, if you find yourself using it then start by asking yourself whether there's an interface missing.

Comment: thx a lot helped me out i wanted to try avoid interface but i guess it was wrong to do so... did it this way works perfect now :D

Comment: interfaces are one of Java's best features - you should use them a lot. In Java 8 with default methods and functional interaces they are even better.

Comment: @czerwix please accept the answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making your `Expenses` and `Incomes` classes implement a common interface, for example `LineItem`.  Now if you use signed values (positive for incomes and negatives for expenses), you only have to call `getValue()` on any implementation of `LineItem` and add it to your running total... no if/else needed, no collection of `Object` needed.

```
public void sumOfAllExpAndIn(){
  int tmp = 0;
  for (Iterator<LineItem> it = database.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
      tmp += it.next().getValue();
    }
  }
  System.out.format("the overall balance is %d",tmp);
}
```